# Svelte: styling the child component from parent component without using :global

Tags: css, sass, tailwind-css, svelte, svelte-component

In a parent component I am passing down a CSS class to child component.

**Parent.svelte**

```
import Child from .Child

<div class="parent-component-class">  
   <Child childClass="child-component-class">
</div>
```

**Child.svelte**

```
export let childClass;
<div class={childClass}></div>
```

I want to be able to style the "*child-component-class*" in the `<style>` tag of a parent component. The only way I found how to do it is using a "global" prefix:

```
<style lang="scss">
:global(.child-component-class){ /*some styles*/ }
</style>
```

But that is not what I want. I want the styling to stay scoped inside the component Parent and down to it's child components. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

That usually is not an issue if you have an element container, you can just use its scoping to ensure that everything is scoped overall.

```css
.parent-component-class :global(.child-component-class) { ...
```

If you do not already have one and it would interfere with layout, you can usually use [`display: contents`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#contents) to avoid that.

By the way, if you want a property named `class` on your components, you can do this:

```js
let className = '';
export { className as class };
```